# basePacakage for many project in swagger2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

i have many packaging example org.dordas.*.web.controller in many project
i want config all project in swagger with one basepackage but * not working .

```
@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.dordas.**.web.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
            .build();
}
```

help me

Answer (score 0):

The base package will not substitute wild cards. You can create your own `Predicate<RequestHandler>` that takes the package of the controller and does a `package.startsWith("org.dorsas")  && package.endsWith("web.controller")`

Comment: i have this problem in other config . example @ControllerAdvice(basePackages = { "org.baharan.{project-name}.web.rest" })